# Algoritmo para geração de nomes

Tags: algoritmo

Pesquisei bastante mas não encontrei um algoritmo que faça algo como os bancos fazem. Por exemplo, quando você se cadastra pela primeira vez em um caixa 24 horas, a máquina irá gerar uma senha. Em geral, é informada 3 ou 4 pares de letras como password.

Entretanto, se observado, as letras que eles geram automaticamente fazem algum sentido se for lido como uma palavra.

Exemplo:

CE LA LU / 
XE GO U

É de conhecimento algo que realize o que desejo?

Obrigado!

Comment: Lista de consoantes e uma de vogais , no laço de repetição escolha alternadamente, vai parecer uma palavra.

Comment: Certo, sem dúvidas, funciona muito bem, @Motta. Obrigado!!! Entretanto, não fica inteligente assim como é gerado nesses sistemas que citei na pergunta. Os pares de siglas ali gerados, fazem algum sentido com palavras do dicionário brasileiro. :)

Comment: @Marcony, esse exemplo do LU LA XE GOU é real mesmo ou criado com base numa lembrança sua? :)

Comment: Real, @brasofilo. Coloquei uma barra para separar porque são duas palavras diferentes. CE LA LU, lembra celular. XE GO U, lembra chegou.

Comment: CELALU lembrar celular é meio forçado. BTW, quer um algoritmo que gera nomes, baixa um dicionário e seleciona palavras de certos tamanhos aleatoriamente ;)

Comment: A minha senha de letras não lembra, em nada, nenhuma palavra. Acho que é meio aleatório mesmo, dentro de um conjunto de silabas.

Comment: A questão é saber : "algo que pareça" ou uma palavra , sendo a segunda a solução do @Renan é a mais viável

Comment: O @PauloHDSousa me deu mais uma ideia, além de escolher uma palavra de um dicionário, usa um dicionário japonês ;)

Comment: Esta pergunta gerou uma [discussão no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1968/ensinar-a-pescar-ou-dar-o-peixe). Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/esclarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fiz um algoritmo deste em 2008. Rodou em PHP.
Eu chamei de "senha pronunciável"

A ideia inicial foi como o comentário do @Motta.
Duas listas: uma de consoantes e uma de vogais:

```
ListaConsoantes = b c d f g j k l m n p r s t v x
ListaVogais = a e i o u
```

Fui aprimorando as consoantes e as vogais para formar palavras mais complexas:

```
ListaConsoantes  = b c d f g j k l m n p r s t v x 
ListaConsoantes2 = ch qu gu lh 
ListaConsoantesFim = s x r l m
ListaVogais      = a e i o u y 
ListaVogais2     = au ei oa ya
```

A função recebia o número de caracteres para a senha a ser gerada, mas este número era encarado como mínimo para o algoritmo poder completar a palavra, não parar no meio de uma sílaba.

Estes fonemas podem ser ampliados e mexidos conforme queira.

o algoritmo ficou mais ou menos assim (em pseudocódigo):

```
size = 8
senha = ''
if ( rand entre 0 ou 1 )
    // inicio com uma vogal simples ou não da ListaVogais [1]
    senha = ListaVogais[ rand ]
while senha.size < size
     // sorteio se uso uma consoante de ListaConsoantes ou ListaConsoantes2 [2]
     if ( rand entre 0 ou 1 )
         senha = senha + ListaConsoantes[ rand ]
     else
         senha = senha + ListaConsoantes2[ rand ]

     // sorteio se uso uma vogal de ListaVogais ou ListaVogais2 [3]
     if ( rand entre 0 ou 1 )
         senha = senha + ListaVogais[ rand ]
     else
         senha = senha + ListaVogais2[ rand ]

     // sorteio se uso uma consoante no fim da palavra [4]
     if ( rand entre 0 ou 1 )
         senha = senha + ListaConsoantesFim[ rand ]
```

Saía, uma senhas bem legais.

podia sair devido à [1]:

> baquichoba ou Abaquichoba

podia sair devido à [2]:

> baQUichoba ou baDichoba

podia sair devido à [3]:

> badOchoba ou badAUchoba

podia sair devido à [4]:

> banichoba ou banichobaS

Comment: +1 pelo esforço. Agora, o ideal seria ter senhas mais aleatórias - é possível fazer um ataque se baseando na semelhança entre as senhas geradas.

Comment: Obrigado, Edinho Almeida! Parabéns pela resposta. Como você disse, é pseudocódigo para que todos possam entender sua ideia e o que elaborou. Valeu pela contribuição, realmente útil.

Comment: Show , deve até rolar umas senhas obscenas ... :)

Comment: mandou bem, baquichoba!